# Timeline App Tabs Icons

Tags: tabs, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

What happens if you don't upload the small icon that sits below the tab image?

What image will it pull?

For example - Facebook Apps - videos will show a reel icon below a visual of the video.

Answer (score 0):

It will show the generic FB app icon:

[image: generic FB app icon]